# how do i have sticky navigation add class after the div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let me start by saying that im trying to create this sticky navigation that after certain scroll, following the page scroll. and it is doable by the following code that adds the navigation a class after certain scroll.

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 90;
    var currentArea = jQuery("section").filter(function() {
        return scroll <= jQuery(this).offset().top + jQuery(this).height();
    });

    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 15) {
        jQuery('.list_title_bar_container').addClass("follow");
    } else if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 15 ) {
        jQuery('.list_title_bar_container').removeClass("follow");
    }
});
});
```

But is there anyway i can add the .follow class only when the scroll reaches the specific navigation div not by using the counting numbers for how much the scroll has been done but by setting a specific div target?

im asking this question, because i have two navigation that needs to be sticky navigation, but it is not calculable exactly where the navigation is and will be, as the position of the navigation differs depending on the page im looking at.

here is the live site if you need to look at : http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/request#

and the sticky navigation im trying to create is this .list_title_bar_container

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div = $('your div name here').offset().top; // get top offset of your div

    if (scroll > div) {
        $('.list_title_bar_container').addClass("follow");
    } else {
        $('.list_title_bar_container').removeClass("follow");
    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLrwrN

Comment: awesome. thanks, i think it's one step closer to the one i want. but there seems to be a bit of a problem. it flickers on and off as the class gets added and removed. can you check this out? http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/request

Comment: Oh. nvm,i think i found the reason why it does that.thanks.